# Converting ASP.net password hash to string swift

Tags: swift

I am using the MSSql database. The encryption process in the Mssql database is encrypted with the same encryption method that asp.net has used. How do I change this password to a normal value? I want to log in according to the data I have taken, but I need to convert passwords. I need to check if the password in the database matches the password in the application.

[image]

The encryption process was done as in the photo. The person who created this data said that he was doing encryption according to asp.net.

I draw data as follows.

```
  let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
        client.connect("asd", username: "asd", password: "asd", database: "asd") { success in
        client.execute("SELECT asd FROM asd", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
         var gifsa: [String] = []
         for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
          for row in table {
          for (_, value) in row {
            if let intVal = value as? String {
                                gifsa.append(String(intVal)) }} }}
          client.disconnect()
        var returnArray: [ImageAsset?] = [ImageAsset]()
            for item in gifsa {
            guard let url = URL(string : item) else {continue}
            let asset = ImageAsset(url: url)
            returnArray.append(asset)
             }
         self.winguGalleryView.assets = returnArray  }) }
```

Comment: Are you sure these passwords are encrypted and not hashed? Because the usual practice for passwords is to be hashed, and in this case you can't restore them. You can check if a password that you have matches the password hash in the DB, but you can't restore a password from the DB.

Comment: I want to check that the password in the DB does not match? How can I do that? @FreeNickname

Comment: In this case you don't actually need to decrypt the passwords in the DB, you just need to take the password that the user entered, apply the same hashing / encryption as the one used in the DB to it and then compare hashes. You need to know the exact encryption / hashing used in the DB though. Can't help you with that, I'm afraid.

Comment: He said that Asp.net was a special type of encryption that he used. Is it necessary to learn the type of this (eg md5 hash) @FreeNickname

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, I'm not familiar with ASP.NET enough to know if it has some "default" encryption method. I'm about 80% sure it should be something standard. You need to know the type of encryption / hashing used in order to work with this DB, that's correct.